# What is the Laghunyasam recited before Sri Rudram? What does it symbolize and represent?

Tags: vedas, mantras, symbolism, hymn

[Sri Rudram Laghunyasam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26255/sri-rudram-laghunyasam)

The above is a question about the "Why" of Laghunyasam. The time, precautions and reasons. However my question is not the same and I ask for what Laghunyasam symbolizes and encompasses. What energy does it invoke?

Comment: Do u have any idea about what  Nyasa is in general and what is the purpose of it? Laghu Nyasa does not serve any different purpose.

Comment: You may find [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22379/4732) answer useful.

Comment: What made you think I don't know what Nyasa is? I am with Yagyopaveetam. Plus I have seen many other verses in Laghunyasam, where there are 2 different sets of invocations. The second mantra comes during the invocation of Aghora Rishi and the first one is the establishing of gods in diff. portions of our body. But then Laghunyasam is not it. There are lots of other verses. My point is why is it called Laghu? And parallel to it, why is MahaNyasam called such? Because Rudram starts much later.

Comment: Where did i say that u don't know what Nyasa is?. That was a question and not an assertion. Laghu means lite or shorter version as opposed to the Mahanyasa.

Comment: I am sorry, that "do you have any idea of what Nyasa is", sounded a bit challenging to me.

Answer (score 3):

Nyasa was already explained [here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22379/4732)

The following explanation on Mahanyasa and Laghunyasa can be found [here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/pashupati5.html?lang=iast).

> **FIVE FACES OF SHIVA**:-
>
> Because of his five faces Shiva has the name pañcavaktraḥ। 
>   pañcasaṅkhyākāni vaktrāṇi mukhāni nānārūpāṇi yasya sa tathā । 
>   (Shivasahasranamam-Padmapuranam).
>
> These faces have the following names. īśāna, tatpuruṣa, aghora,
>   vāmadeva, and sadyojāta. These faces face up the sky, East, South,
>   North and West respectively. It seems that a lingam with five faces as
>   described here is to be seen only in the Pashupati temple in Nepal and
>   the temple attached to the Shankara math in Tiruvanaikkaval near
>   Trichy. The hymn given in the beginning has salutations to the five
>   faces of the Lord.
>
> We have the salutations to Shiva's five faces in ***Mahanyasam*** that
>   is chanted before chanting the vedic hymn Shri Rudram. There are two
>   Nyasams, the **Mahanyasam** and the **Laghunyasam**.
>
> Maha(mahat)  means big. Laghu is the opposite,(laghu)  means light,
>   not heavy. The Mahanyasam is a part of the methodology of chanting of
>   the Rudram on special occasions such as Pradosham, Shivaratri.
>
> Typically, during a **Rudra parayanam at home, one recites the
>   Laghunyasam**.
>
> Such a Shri Rudra parayanam in a **public place of worship such as a
>   temple** is preceeded by the recital of the **Mahanyasam**.
>
> As the name difference indicates, the Laghunyasam is shorter.
>
> The Mahanyasam invokes the deity of Shri Rudra in His many forms of
>   Indra, Agni, Yama, Varuna etc in the different limbs (anga's) of the
>   one who chants. Such an invoking is done to seek the blessings of the
>   Lord, and at the same time giving one and all a feeling of immediate
>   presence of the Lord in the vicinity of the chanting. The Mahanyasam
>   has certain chapters of the Shri Rudram, the Purusha Suktam etc
>   repeated in it. The Shiva samkalpam is also part of this.